# how to create a read function in mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, database

I am new to asp.net and c#. How do i come up with a read function? There is a red line under the word read.

The following codes below are what i have code out for now.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;



namespace P1
{
    public class EPSData
    {
        private MySqlConnection con = null;
        private MySqlCommand cmd = null;
        private MySqlDataReader rdr;
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet(cmd,con); //
        //private MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        //private DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        public string read()
        {
            con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=staff;Uid=root;Pwd=password");

            con.Open();

            string cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM approver WHERE ID = 'ApproverID';";


            cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = cmdStr;
            cmd.Connection = con;


            con.Close();

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: What is `read()` supposed to return?  Also, .Net programming conventions dictate that method names start with an uppercase letter, also known as Pascal Case.

Answer (score 0):

Your read() method doesn't have any return statement.

You declare a string value to be returned by your read method so you have to do

```
return "Some String value";
```

[Here's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html) some information about MysqlCommand Class and usage. You can find lot of informations on the internet.

Comment: so i'll just put return read(); at the bottom of con.Close(); ? 

for instance if i want it to return approverID, i will return approverID(); ?

Comment: I suggest you to read more about ADO.net and data retrieving process.. You have to use your MySQLDataReader to get and manipulate your datas

Answer (score 0):

Your method `public string read()` determines that it will return `string` while you are not returning `string` from the method body. Either declare your method return type as `void` or add `return "some str";` as the `last line` in the `method body`.

Comment: so i'll just put return read(); at the bottom of con.Close(); ? for instance if i want it to return approverID, i will return approverID(); ?

Comment: In last line you could do return 'ApproverID';

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually retrieve the data you want to return and then return that with a return statement.

Putting `return read();` at the end will not solve your issue.  That would just cause the method to re-call itself until you ran out of memory or got a stack overflow.